# gcc does not include extern variables in symbol table when optimisation is used

Tags: c, gcc

My program contains many externally defined variables. When I compile it with -O0 flag, I see them in the symbol table, but not when I use -O1 or -O2. How can I force the compiler to export them?

```
foo.c:
    extern const int my_symbol;

    void my_fn()
    {
        void *x = &my_symbol;
        // but x is not used, that's probably why it is optimised out
    }

nm foo.o (with O0):
    U my_symbol

nm foo.o (with O2):
    <my_symbol absent>
```

Comment: Did you really use that `my_symbol` in your `foo.c`?

Comment: The symptoms suggest that the variable has been optimized out. Try using it and doing something that can't be optimized out. For example, `printf` its value, and don't have its value defined in this file.

Comment: @user3638885 If you do not use it in your `foo.c`, why do you declare it in that source file in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. my_symbol is in fact used in a function below. I've updated the question.

Comment: @user3638885 It looks like you already guessed the answer of your problem.

Comment: When I add __attribute__((used)), I get `warning: 'used' attribute ignored`

Answer (score 3):

If your `foo.c` only (essentially) has

```
extern const int my_symbol;
```

then compile it with `-O1` or `-O2`, that symbol will be optimized out. However, if you use that symbol in `foo.c`, for example

```
extern const int my_symbol;
extern int my_flag;

void foo(void)
{
    if (my_symbol)
        my_flag = 1;
}
```

All of those symbols will exist in `foo.o` even if you compile it with `-O1` or `-O2`.

Answer (score 1):

With `-O1' and '-O2', the compiler tries to reduce code size and execution time.  One of the optimizations used to reduce the size of the resulting executable is to 'throw everything overboard' that is not required for execution.  The symbol table of an executable is one of those debugging niceties that is really not required for execution; so it is excluded from the final output file.

('-O0' means "Do no optimizations").